# How to disable automatic graphics switching on iMac?

Tags: mac, graphics-card

I am trying to disable my iGPU because it is using it by default for gaming instead of my NVIDIA card. I have done research and found that this is the way to do it, but when I went to go find the setting, it's not there. I know for a fact that I do have the integrated intel graphics and a NVIDIA card so the problem is not that I don't have 2 video cards. What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The setting is in System Preferences > Energy Saver. What model is your iMac and what version is your OS?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I don't think iMac would have a Battery tab.

Comment: @L_K they don't. Also the few apps that let you switch manually are only compatible with MacBooks.